# c# How to fetch targetNamespace from XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML documents:

```
<ABC: EXAMPLE xmlns: ABC = "www.xyz.com" targetNamespace = "www.pqr.com">
//BODY
</ABC:EXAMPLE>
```

OR

```
<ORDER targetNamespace = "www.pqr.com">
BODY
</ORDER>
```

I tried this-

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
 xmlNamespace = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
```

But this would only return me `www.xyz.com` and `null` respectively from the above two documents.

How do I fetch `targetNamespace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetNamespace` is an attribute on the XML element `ABC:EXAMPLE`, and not standard XML, so there isn't a property directly on the XmlDocument for you to get it. You need to access it using the `Attributes` property. Like so:

```cs
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

// This is the namespace of the element 'ABC:EXAMPLE', so "www.xyz.com"
xmlNamespace = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;

// This is the value of the attribute 'targetNamespace', so "www.pqr.com"
xmlTargetNamespace = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes["targetNamespace"].Value;
```

You can use the Attributes property on any XmlElement to access it's attributes, you can use named indexing and Value property on the XmlNode to access the value